# Temporal locality with regard to data access and temporal locality with regard to data fetch

Tags: cpu-architecture, instructions, temporal

I am stuck with a question which is stated below,

> Describe the general characteristics and behavior of a program that would exhibit:
>       (a) Low temporal locality with regard to data accesses
>       (b) Low temporal locality with regard to instruction fetches

I understand temporal locality, but I am unable to understand what does it mean with regard to data access and instruction fetch. I would be very thankful if someone could explain it to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're talking about optimising caches for accessing data and instructions in a CPU. Essentially, low temporal locality means that something that is re-used frequently, but not in one big chunk (i.e. spread over time).

Example of low temporal locality:

```
read file
process data
output result
....
read file
process data
output result
....
read file
process data
output result
```

To improve this you can re-arrange so that all reads are done together, all processing is done together, and all outputs are done together.

In the context of a CPU, you can say that if you need to do a memory read frequently, just read it once and cache it, then do as much as you can with it before discarding it. For instructions this means keeping things like looped instructions in a very fast cache (usually L1). For data, it means caching whatever you use most.

See these links for a proper explanation:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/temporal-locality
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference#Use_of_spatial_and_temporal_locality:_hierarchical_memory

Comment: I am still confused about temporal locality for both. Which one of the two (instruction fetch/data access) have you given in the example?

Comment: The example was for both. The read, process and output operations will have blocks of code associated with them. In its current state, each block of code would be fetched from memory, then executed. If the operations were clustered (i.e. read,read,read,process,process,process,out,out,out) the code blocks can be read from memory once each instead of 3 times each. The same applies for any variables or data used by the operations.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please elaborate that should the temporal locality be high or low in general. Which on is better?

Comment: High is better. High temporal locality means "things that are used more frequently (or frequently in relation to each other) are stored closer together, or somewhere faster". It's a concept used in mechanical drives, too. If you've got a file that you know you will be sequentially reading, make the blocks that contain the file data _local_ to each other, and don't fragment them across 500 different locations on disk.

Comment: Can't I say that the program has low temporal locality because the instruction/data used once was not used again? So the program had less number of occurrences of that data?

Comment: The point is that the data **IS** re-used, during the second and third occurances of each operation. But they're not re-used in a way that would allow them to be cached efficiently. The description of temporal locality as _high_ or _low_ comes from something being "more local" or "less local".

Comment: So the given example is of a low temporal locality? If so, then the answers to my questions should be,
(a) The program is not optimized for data to be reused often.
(b) The program is not optimized for instructions to be used often.
Is it so?

Comment: Yes, that's the case, though your current phrasing isn't optimal. You may want to specify that you're talking about the _caching_ of data and instructions, rather than just say "it's not optimized".

Answer (score 1):

- Low temporal locality for code means no loops and no reuse of instructions.
- High temporal locality for code means tight loops with lots of reuse.
- Low spatial locality for code means lots of jumps to far away places.
- High spatial locality for code means no branches/jumps at all.

REFERENCE: Computer Organization and Design: The Hardware/Software Interface